# How to render objects from the backend's JSON? (Child not showing up)

Tags: json, reactjs, socket.io, render

tldr:
My objects are not rendering.

Explanation:
I am retrieving the following JSON object from the backend:

```
{
  "queued": 0,
  "status": "on_timeout",
  "cartId": "1bcadd2fea88"
}
```

In my `componentDidMount()` method, I am logging `InfoData` as the object after establishing socket.io connection with the backend and am able to do that successfully, as seen below in the 1st and 3rd console logs. The 3rd log has been parsed using the following line: `this.InfoData = JSON.parse(data)`

I have tried using `keys` and by doing very basic rendering (see code below), but with no success (I believe I am not doing them right).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

class Information extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      InfoData: [],
      endpoint: 'http://someNetworkICantShare/admin'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { endpoint } = this.state
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint)
    socket.on('success', data => {
      console.log('data:\n', data)
      console.log('data.status:\n', data.status)
      this.InfoData = JSON.parse(data) //parsed
      console.log('parsed data:\n', JSON.parse(data))
      console.log('data.status after parsed:\n', data.status)
      console.log('status:\n', this.InfoData.status)
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { InfoData } = this.state
    console.log('IndoData:\n', InfoData)
    console.log('IndoData.cartId not returning:\n', InfoData.cartId)
      return (
          <div>
            <p>{InfoData}</p> {/** entire JSON is rendering */}
            <p>{InfoData.status}</p> {/** status is not rendering */}
          </div>
      )
  }
}

export default Information
```

Please let me know if additional information is required, and I apologize if this is poorly worded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mutating the state

```
this.InfoData = JSON.parse(data)
```

Should be

```
this.setState({ InfoData : JSON.parse(data) })
```